# Right Click context menu customization for Web browser control

Tags: c#, c++, webbrowser-control, contextmenu, com-interop

I am currently making my custom web browser application using C# (using .net 2012 visual studio). I make use of the webBrowser component which I can found in the toolbox. When running my application, and right click on the webbrowser component, I got the default context menu (that come with the Internet explorer).

Goal: My aim is to customize this default context menu. Customize here means i still want the default context menu, but wanna `remove/disable/add` options to this default context menu.

I have implemented to make use of `IDocHostUIHandler` interfaces , to catch the event where the context menu is about to be shown.

Here is the snippet of code :

```
IDocHostUIHandler.ShowContextMenu(uint dwID, ref tagPOINT ppt, object pcmdtReserved, object pdispReserved)
```

Question: I am not clear upon how to implement this scenery. `throw new ComException("", OK)` doesn't even return the default context menu. I have some sample in C++ but unable to replicate the same in c#.  Microsoft help file did have codes for modifying existing default context menu ,such as removing the view source option from the context menu, but the code is in C++!!!!!!  Anyone can help me on this.

Thanks you.

Comment: That context menu is not customizable.  You have to *replace* it.

Comment: Thanks Hans, But do you mean that it would not be cutomizable using c#..